# Are RPCs bi-directional?

Tags: networking, rpc

Do remote procedure calls support bi-directional communication?

I. e. is it possible to build a communication mechanism

- using "pure" RPC (**without** any protocols on top of it like XML-RPC, JSON-RPC, Thrift etc.), which
- allows two machines to exchange messages in **both** directions (from machine 1 to machine 2 and vice versa) ?

Comment: It depends upon the actual RPC protocol. It may be called asynchronous RPC, and that is not remote procedure *calls* anymore (but just asynchronous messages exchange abusing the same RPC protocol). And the two parties could also be both RPC clients & servers at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old well known RPC (ONC RPC/ SUN RPC) are allow bi-directional connections. Of course at the end you need an implementation which will support that. The is a fork of ti-rpc maintained by LinuxBox https://github.com/mattbenjamin/libtirpc-lbx and a java implementation http://code.google.com/p/nio-jrpc/ with bi-directional rpc support. Both libraries used in  NFSv4.1 server/client implementations which require bi-directional RPC.